# Lib files are listed in MANIFEST.MF and present in lib folder but some of the libs (JavaFX and PostgreSQL) won't load

Tags: java, postgresql, javafx, ant, classpath

I have an application that is compiled using Ant on Netbeans 12. The application used to run pretty well with 'java -jar *"applicationjar"*' command using JRE8 but it does not work using JDK 11 and higher versions of JDK.

All dependent lib files are in my lib folder and I can see references for each lib files in the manifest file but for some reason postgresql and javafx libraries cannot be found at run-time.

I have to include these specific lib files in my classpath and MS Windows cannot take all of them so it is challenging to use it as a standard desktop application.

Your assistance will be much appreciated

Comment: JavaFX libraries must be on the module path, not the class path. See the getting started instructions at openjfx.io. Also see [eden coding](https://edencoding.com/runtime-components-error/).

Comment: You may also want to check out the "Packaging" section of the [javafx tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried the advice from endencoding.com by creating a batch file but still got the error:  Mar 19, 2022 9:01:59 AM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @2554c898'
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found .......

Comment: Contents of my batch file : java.exe -cp funsofthmis.jar;C:\Users\cwawe\Documents\funsofthmis\lib\postgresql-42.2.5.jar com.afrisoftech.sys.SplashScreenDialog --module-path C:\Users\cwawe\Documents\funsofthmis\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media, javafx.graphics, javafx.base, javafx.web, jvafx-swt

Comment: The application launches successfully but the form with the JavaFX feature does not load